# Does Kismac 0.3.3 (0.3.3) work on Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: wifi, macos

Does Kismac 0.3.3 (0.3.3) built on February 7th work on Mac OSX 10.8.2

It doesn't seem to scan for me.

Both are the latest versions as of today.

Comment: What wireless card are you using?

Comment: http://easymactips.blogspot.in/2011/07/kismac-and-os-x-lion-107-solution.html i hope it helps

Comment: Or just get r407 from http://trac.kismac-ng.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: I'm using Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are some issues with KisMAC on 10.7 and later, so you should [grab the r407 nightly build from the wiki](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/wiki/Downloads).

Also check that your wifi card is supported. The Alfa AWUS036H (RTL8187L USB chipset) is listed as supported, but doesn't actually work on Mac OS 10.6.7 or later. The internal wifi card on MacBooks is also known to work with *certain* Apple drivers, but I don't know which. I'd suggest looking for a USB wireless dongle that uses the Ralink RT2570 or Ralink RT73 chipset, since they seem to be best supported.